# Failed to deploy web package to App Service in ASE3

Tags: azure-devops

I have set up a ASE3 environment to which I am deploying my app service through azure-devops yaml-pipeline. I have an agent-pool on a windows-scaleset that i have created in the same vNet as the ASE3 but on a different subnet.

When the pipeline is excuted it throws the following error in the deploy-task:

```
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx.4:443
##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx.4:443
```

Any help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by checking the routing table. It seemed that the subnet where build-agent is hosted had next-hop to outside the vNet which made ASEs ip-address unknown to the firewall. by changing that could the agent upload the zip-packege.